# Product Name not changing in URL when ID is modified ASP.Net Webform

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting, webforms

I have a ASP.Net Webforms application with framework 4.5.

I have a page where product is displayed. The url is /product/Toy1/toy1_ID.

If I change ID part i.e. toy1_ID to toy2_ID, the page displays toy2 but URL remains same /product/Toy1/toy2_ID.

Is there a way to update URL with Toy2 (name of product) in URL if ID part is changed

required URL = /product/Toy2/toy2_ID

If ID is changed then name of product should change in URL

Comment: You sure this is web forms? Pages end in .aspx?

Comment: Unless you're doing some sort of Url Rewriting in WebForms,this does look like MVC routing.

Comment: Can you show your current URL rewrite?

Comment: Are you changing that ID in code behind? Since you already in a post back, then consider just using response.write("new url here") in place of code behind JUST changing the value of id.

Comment: @wazz - asp.net (even web forms) projects are defaulted to what we call "friendly URL's" and this default setting is out of the box - even for asp.net + web forms. True the file extension is aspx, but we tend to not even type that in, or display it, or even use it anymore - and it been that way for some time. So now the additional "/" actually becomes the parameter.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that. I've turned it off a couple times.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I am changing the ID in URL itself.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be more brute force than necessary, but in one of our sites we have a similar URL rewrite, and what we do to resolve such a situation is, in the productpage.aspx.cs code, we get the id and name from the URL and check to see if the url name matches the name for that id in the database. If it doesn't, we build a url with the correct name for that id and do a 301 redirect to it.

Comment: I am doing the rewrite inside the productpage.aspx.cs too. It make sense to check put a check on it then redirect. I'll try that and then mark your suggestion as answer if it works